# Compile and build lp_solve from source code, ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lpsolve

I am using ubuntu machine and I've downloaded lp_solve source (lp_solve_5.5.2.5_source.tar.gz) and unpack it. Then I cd my command prompt into the path, lp_solve_5.5/lpsolve55.
Then I run command

```
./ccc
```

Then I got this error and created empty bin folder.

```
In file included from ../lp_SOS.c:3:0:
../shared/commonlib.h:88:24: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
   #define FALSE        0
                        ^
In file included from ../lp_utils.c:4:0:
../shared/commonlib.h:88:24: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
   #define FALSE        0
                        ^
cc: error: lp_MDO.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_crash.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_wlp.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_matrix.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_mipbb.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_MPS.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_params.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_presolve.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_price.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_pricePSE.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_scale.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_simplex.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: lp_SOS.o: No such file or directory
```

I am not familiar with Ubuntu. I'll be grateful to you, If any one can help me to solve this problem. I want to use CFM-ID algorithm for my project. To use it I have to install lp_solve correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this post helped me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prismmodelchecker/gtVatHAir90

1. Download the patch https://groups.google.com/group/prismmodelchecker/attach/3586984674e863/fix-lpsolve-compilation.patch?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1
2. Apply the patch with `patch < yourpath/fix-lpsolve-compilation.patch` inside the directory with the `ccc` file.
3. However this will not find the right files to patch, since the patch was intended for some PRISM version - you have to **specify** the corresponding file. For example

   ```
   can't find file to patch at input line 57
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |Index: prism/ext/lpsolve55/src/lp_solve_5.5/lpsolve55/ccc
   |===================================================================
   |--- prism/ext/lpsolve55/src/lp_solve_5.5/lpsolve55/ccc (revision 11215)
   |+++ prism/ext/lpsolve55/src/lp_solve_5.5/lpsolve55/ccc (revision 11216)
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   ```

   There you enter `ccc`. You don't need to get all of them right (the ccc.osx etcetera), so you can just skip all except for the "right" ccc.